# How to reduce the number of features for Gaussian Process regression?

Tags: feature-selection, gaussian-process

Ridge regression reduces complexity of the model by scaling down the coefficient.
Lasso reduces the complexity of the model by selecting the features used.

For Gaussian Process, is there similar way to actually select the relevant features for the model? I know that there is a way to automatically determine the relevance of the features by comparing the length scales of the covariance function, but it does not actually select the features.

In addition, the complexity seems to be defined either by the number of parameters used or the smoothness of the trained model. In that sense, the noise variance in the GP model can also possibly control the complexity of the model? I observe that larger variance results in more smooth and generalized regression model.